# Code explanation for bitmap conversion

Tags: c#-4.0, bitmap

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574798/159072

```
public static Bitmap BitmapTo1Bpp(Bitmap img) 
{
  int w = img.Width;
  int h = img.Height;
  //
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
  BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
```

Why this addition and division?

```
  byte[] scan = new byte[(w + 7) / 8];
  for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) 
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) 
    {////Why this condition check?
      if (x % 8 == 0) 
      //Why divide by 8?
      scan[x / 8] = 0;
      Color c = img.GetPixel(x, y);
      //Why this condition check?
      if (c.GetBrightness() >= 0.5)
      { 
           // What is going on here?
           scan[x / 8] |= (byte)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
      }
    }
    // Why Martial.Copy() called here?
    Marshal.Copy(scan, 0, (IntPtr)((long)data.Scan0 + data.Stride * y), scan.Length);
  }
  bmp.UnlockBits(data);
  return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses some basic bit-hacking techniques, required because it needs to set bits and the minimum storage element you can address in C# is a byte.  I intentionally avoided using the BitArray class.

```
   int w = img.Width;
```

I copy the Width and Height properties of the bitmap into a local variable to speed up the code, the properties are too expensive.  Keep in mind that `w` are the number of pixels across the bitmap, it represents the number of *bits* in the final image.

```
   byte[] scan = new byte[(w + 7) / 8];
```

The `scan` variable stores the pixels in one scan line of the bitmap.  The 1bpp format uses 1 bit per pixel so the total number of bytes in a scan line is w / 8.  I add 7 to ensure the value is rounded up, necessary because integer division always truncates.  w = 1..7 requires 1 byte, w = 8..15 requires 2 bytes, etcetera.

```
   if (x % 8 == 0) scan[x / 8] = 0;
```

The `x % 8` expression represents the bit number, `x / 8` is the byte number.  This code sets all the pixels to Black when it progresses to the next byte in the scan line.  Another way to do it would be re-allocating the byte[] in the outer loop or resetting it back to 0 with a for-loop.

```
   if (c.GetBrightness() >= 0.5)
```

The pixel should be set to White when the source pixel is bright enough.  Otherwise it leaves it at Black.  Using Color.Brightness is a simple way to avoid dealing with the human eye's non-linear perception of brightness (luminance ~= 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue).

```
   scan[x / 8] |= (byte)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
```

Sets a bit to White in the scan line.  As noted `x % 8` is the bit number, it shifts 0x80 to the right by the bit number, they are stored in reverse order in this pixel format.